# How to parse tag attributes with BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I am wondering how could I use BeautifulSoup to parse this style (javascript?) of tag attributes in the following html code:

```
<div class="class1" data-prop="{personName: 'Claudia', personCode:'123456'}">
...
</div>
```

I'm currently just following standard process until I reach the contents of the attribute which I am currently parsing using regexp, however I'd like to know if there are better/faster/more elegant options:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
class_element = soup.find("div", class_="class1")
data-props=class_element['data-prop']
# Parsing using regexp goes here
```

Comment: `import json; data = json.loads(data_props)`?

Comment: @buran Oh, I'm sorry, now I see why

Comment: Yes, that does not work. I already tried that.

Comment: OP can you specify what or how do you parse using regexp? You may be interested in another way of parsing with regexp?

Comment: possible duplicate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284422/get-data-from-a-script-var-with-beautifulsoup/69285587#69285587

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that this is a faster approach than regexp, but the one that probably takes less lines of code:
To turn this string into a python `dict`

```py
data_props = "{personName: 'Claudia', personCode:'123456'}"

data_as_dict_str = "dict(" + data_props[1:-1].replace(":", "=") + ")"

print(eval(data_as_dict_str))
# {'personName': 'Claudia', 'personCode': '123456'}
```

If this attribute contains malicious Python code, it will be executed (in the `eval`)!
And we also cannot use the safe `ast.literal_eval`, since it will not allow the name `dict` to be called

If we wanna use `ast.literal_eval` or `json` then we need to transform this string in a way that all first names will have quotes around them and at this point it'll be easier to only use regexp:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\b\w+\b)\s*:\s*'([^']+)'")

data_props = "{personName: 'Claudia', personCode:'123456'}"

print(dict(pattern.findall(data_props)))
# {'personName': 'Claudia', 'personCode': '123456'}
```

Comment: @fazineroso if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is simply handling unquoted keys then you can use hjson library. I have no idea about the under-the-hood efficiencies, how regex is used within the parser etc, but it is nice and simple to use at the top level:

```
import hjson

data = hjson.loads(soup.select_one('.class1')['data-prop'])
```